# R - delete consecutive (ONLY) duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates, delete-row, repeat

I need to eliminate rows from a data frame based on the repetition of values in a given column, but only those that are consecutive.
For example, for the following data frame:

```
df = data.frame(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,4,2,2,1))
df$y <- c(10,11,30,12,49,13,12,49,30)
df$z <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)

x  y z
1 10 1
1 11 2
1 30 3
2 12 4
2 49 5
4 13 6
2 12 7
2 49 8
1 30 9
```

I would need to eliminate rows with consecutive repeated values in the x column, keep the last repeated row, and maintain the structure of the data frame:

```
x  y z
1 30 3
2 49 5
4 13 6
2 49 8
1 30 9
```

Following directions from `help` and some other posts, I have tried using the `duplicated` function:

```
df[ !duplicated(x,fromLast=TRUE), ] # which gives me this:
      x  y  z
1     1 10  1
6     4 13  6
7     2 12  7
9     1 30  9
NA   NA NA NA
NA.1 NA NA NA
NA.2 NA NA NA
NA.3 NA NA NA
NA.4 NA NA NA
NA.5 NA NA NA
NA.6 NA NA NA
NA.7 NA NA NA
NA.8 NA NA NA
```

Not sure why I get the NA rows at the end (wasn't happening with a similar table I was testing), but works only partially on the values.

I have also tried using the `data.table` package as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)           
setkey(dt, x)                    
dt[J(unique(x)), mult ='last']
```

Works great, but it eliminates ALL duplicates from the data frame, not just those that are consecutive, giving something like this:

```
x  y z
1 30 9
2 49 8
4 13 6
```

Please, forgive if cross-posting. I tried some of the suggestions but none worked for eliminating only those that are consecutive.
I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `inx <- with(df, c(FALSE, diff(x) != 0)); df[c(diff(cumsum(inx)) != 0, TRUE), ]`. (I am not sure that I like it, one too many `diff`.)

Comment: @Rui, maybe not elegant but does the job, thanks! what does the `c(FALSE, diff(x) !=0)` do? Sorry, I'm a newbie and trying to learn. I understand if you don't have the time to elaborate. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to check in there is no duplicate following a number, i.e x[i+1] != x[i] and note the last value will always be present.

```
df[c(df$x[-1] != df$x[-nrow(df)],TRUE),]
  x  y z
3 1 30 3
5 2 49 5
6 4 13 6
8 2 49 8
9 1 30 9
```

Comment: I tried doing something similar `df[!(x[i] == x[i+1])` but I got lost in the syntax. Neat and simple, thanks

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
df[cumsum(rle(df$x)$lengths),]
```

Explanation:

```
rle(df$x)
```

gives you the run lengths and values of *consecutive* duplicates in the `x` variable. Then:

```
rle(df$x)$lengths
```

extracts the lengths. Finally:

```
cumsum(rle(df$x)$lengths)
```

gives the row indices which you can select using `[`.

**EDIT** for fun here's a `microbenchmark` of the answers given so far with `rle` being mine, `consec` being what I think is the most fundamentally direct answer, given by @James, and would be the answer I would "accept", and `dp` being the `dplyr` answer given by @Nik.

```
#> Unit: microseconds
#>    expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max
#>     rle   134.389   145.4220   162.6967   154.4180   172.8370    375.109
#>  consec   111.411   118.9235   136.1893   123.6285   145.5765    314.249
#>      dp 20478.898 20968.8010 23536.1306 21167.1200 22360.8605 179301.213
```

`rle` performs better than I thought it would.

Comment: thanks! I've seen `rle` being used before for other purposes. Some people says it may fail with large data sets, but it works here!

Comment: My computer was perfectly happy to run `rle(sample(1:10000, 1e8, repl=TRUE))` in about 10 seconds. So I don't think `rle` is going to be the issue.

Comment: thanks for the info on performance, and for the explanations, I learned a lot.

Comment: Thank you for the `microbenchmark`. An eye opener for me

Answer (score 2):

A cheap solution with `dplyr` that I could think of:

Method:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(id = lag(x, 1), 
         decision = if_else(x != id, 1, 0), 
         final = lead(decision, 1, default = 1)) %>% 
  filter(final == 1) %>% 
  select(-id, -decision, -final)
```

Output:

```
  x  y z
1 1 30 3
2 2 49 5
3 4 13 6
4 2 49 8
5 1 30 9
```

This will even work if your data has the same x value at the bottom

New Input:

```
df2 <- df %>% add_row(x = 1, y = 10, z = 12)
df2

   x  y  z
1  1 10  1
2  1 11  2
3  1 30  3
4  2 12  4
5  2 49  5
6  4 13  6
7  2 12  7
8  2 49  8
9  1 30  9
10 1 10 12
```

Use same method:

```
df2 %>% 
  mutate(id = lag(x, 1), 
         decision = if_else(x != id, 1, 0), 
         final = lead(decision, 1, default = 1)) %>% 
  filter(final == 1) %>% 
  select(-id, -decision, -final)
```

New Output:

```
  x  y  z
1 1 30  3
2 2 49  5
3 4 13  6
4 2 49  8
5 1 10 12
```

Comment: I didn't think on using `dplyr::` like this. It'll be very helpful, thanks. Some unrelated question, and sorry in advance for the simplicity: what does `%>%` do? I've seen it quite often and I don't seem to be able to find an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution. The trick is to create a shifted version of `x` with the `shift` function and compare it with `x`

```
library(data.table)
dattab <- as.data.table(df)
dattab[x != shift(x = x, n = 1, fill = -999, type = "lead")] # edited to add closing )
```

This way you compare each value of x with its immediately following value and throw out where they match. Make sure to set fill to something that is not in `x` in order for correct handling of the last value.

Comment: I was curious on how to achieve this with `data.table::`, thanks. This seems like the `data.table::` vs of the `dplyr::` response by @ Nik. Never thought of shifting/lagging the column. Is a nice roundabout to keep in mind.

Comment: I'd say this is the same logic as @James. Another `data.table` solution using run length encoding (i.e. `rle`) would be `dattab[, grp:=rleid(x)][,.SD[.N], by=grp][, -"grp"]`. What this does is: add a variable called `grp` based on the run length group. Then pick the last line within each group. Then delete the `grp` variable.

Comment: Same logic, yes. I have to admit I did not read his code carefully enough before I posted. I like your solution, though. Did not know `rleid`.