# How to remove all consecutive data but keep only the first row

Tags: r, duplicates

Referring to this question: [R - delete consecutive (ONLY) duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306833/r-delete-consecutive-only-duplicates/49307760#49307760?newreg=5e0389c1eaf74127b30797cb642b6c7d)
I am using the same formula:

```
df[c(df$x[-1] != df$x[-nrow(df)],TRUE),]
```

But I am only having the last values and I want to fist ones how can I change that?
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few options.

First, you can use `rle` to get indices of consecutive values. To keep the first value in a series of consecutive numbers, start with index of 1, and add the other indices cumulatively.

```
lens <- rle(df$x)$lengths
df[cumsum(c(1, lens[-length(lens)])), ]
```

As an alternative, using `tidyverse` you can create groups where there is a difference in `x` by rows. You could keep the first value in each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(grp = c(T, diff(x) != 0)) %>%
  filter(grp) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Or with `data.table` you can use `rleid` (function to gerate run-length type group id). Duplicates are `FALSE`. Keep rows where *not* `FALSE` allows you to keep the first row among repeats.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[!duplicated(rleid(x))]
```